# Remove blank lines from xml stored as string in Table

Tags: sql, regexp-replace

I have a table MyTable with a column named "record" which has an XML stored as a String. I want to remove all blank lines from that XML.

**Input:**

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>

<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**Schema Definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  record TEXT
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (record)
VALUES ('<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>

<body>Don''t forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>');
```

**What I tried:**

```
SELECT regexp_replace(record, '(?m)^\s*\r?\n(?!(\s*\r?\n))', '') AS record
FROM MyTable;
```

Although the above removed the first blank line, it didn't remove the last one.

**Link to Try:** https://app.coderpad.io/R9AH7H79

Comment: Please edit your question, and tag only one database

Answer (score 0):

Should be sufficient to replace double newline symbols with single ones:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(record, '\n\n', '\n') AS record
FROM MyTable;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6ES9Ut8wmY1gTAnZ6n119/0).

Note: this should work both in MySQL and PostgreSQL.